# Washing machine randomly trips GFCI

Tags: gfci

I have a new Samsung washer, sometime when washing the GFCI will trip, but only occasionally and not at any set point in the wash cycle. The GFCI is the only device on the circuit and is wired correctly and functions properly. The outlet is close to washer box (drain supply) but there are no leaks or signs drain is over flowing. I am a retired commercial superintendent and am familiar with electrical and plumbing. I used my GFCI tester to check proper wiring and function. I have used my temp gun to check for high humidity and was no higher than anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the GFCI itself is not faulty, there are basically three possibilities:

##### Water intrusion on the GFCI/receptacle

A typical GFCI/receptacle has a duplex receptacle. One receptacle is used for the washing machine. If:

- The second receptacle is open (nothing plugged in)
- The receptacle is *not* weather-resistant
- There is some water spray near the receptacle - e.g., due to splashing from a drain hose into a sink

then there is a possibility you are getting some water intrusion into the second receptacle, causing a GFCI trip.

I kind of doubt this is the case. An easy way to make sure this is not what is happening is to plug something (lamp, USB charger, whatever) into the second receptacle. If the problem goes away then you have found both the source of the problem and an easy fix.

##### Motor or electronics causing a problem

This has been reported by many people, but I have never seen it myself (but I am not a professional electrician so my experience is limited). I would expect far more problems with AFCI than with GFCI. But it is *possible* that, for example, a faulty motor could cause intermittent GFCI trips.

##### An actual water-caused ground fault

I think this is the most likely problem. Either due to poor design or faulty manufacturing or a crack in some part somewhere, water occasionally makes its way from the washing machine tub to electric parts, wiring, etc. inside the washing machine. That causes an actual ground fault, and the GFCI trips.

Beyond the first possibility (easy!), this is going to be hard to diagnose. I suggest contacting Samsung. All new consumer-grade appliances in the US should be designed to work properly with GFCI and AFCI protection. That was not the case a few decades ago, but as all new houses require GFCI and/or AFCI on almost every circuit, the manufacturers have been forced to adapt - redesigning equipment in some cases to make sure it works. Whether caused by marginal design, a manufacturing flaw or even a post-installation problem (except, of course, physical damage from misuse) should be a warranty issue.